# Can I have two apps under same (custom)Tab

Tags: php, facebook

As I am stumbling through Facebook App Dev. I am getting more and more close to a bit sophisticated questions, bu still I am at newbie level.

Can I have custom Tab and inside that tab two different apps ?
ex. (the slideshow and top 5 news(RSS feed))

Answer (score 0):

No you can not.
But - if you create your own application you can include a slideshow and an rss feed into the same application and have that in your custom tab.